# iOS Timer in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, uitableview

I have tableview with multiple cells, each cell has a button,
When the button is clicked the button is disabled and the timer starts for 30 sec. After the 30 sec is done the button should be enabled again. There is label under the button which should count down how many seconds left for the button to be enabled again.

1- The problem is when the user scroll the button gets enabled again, because the cell is reusable. 
How to avoid that?

2- how to show time left for that cell? .. Reusable cell causing the problem again

Sample of the code..

```
/// Table View Code
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell1";
    static NSString *simple2TableIdentifier = @"cell2";


    Cell1 *cell = (Cell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    Cell2 *cell2 = (Cell2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simple2TableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"xxxxxx" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    if (cell2 == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yyyyyyyyy" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    if(![[[self.info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"someKeyGoesHere"]isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        cell.some_id.text=[[self.info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"order_id"];

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        if ([[[self.info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:ccc] isEqualToString:@"2"] && ([tempo isEqualToString:uu] || [tempo isEqualToString:bbb]) )
        {
            cell.btn.hidden=NO;
            cell.btn.tag=[[[self.info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"some_id"] integerValue];
            [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btn.hidden=YES;
        }

        if(!cell.btn.isHidden)
        {
            if([[Manager btns]containsObject:cell.btn])
            {
                cell.btn.enabled=NO;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.btn.enabled=YES;
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////


        return cell;

    }
    else
    {
        ///some code
        return cell2;
    }


}


-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"A: %li",(long)sender.tag);
    [Manager startTimer:sender];

}


//Sigleton Code

-(void)startTimer:(UIButton*)btn
{
    NSLog(@"start");
    btn.enabled=NO;
    [btns addObject:btn];
    NSLog(@"O_O: %li",(long)btn.tag);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(stopTimer:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
-(void)stopTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{

    NSLog(@"stop");
    [timer invalidate];
    ((UIButton *)[btns firstObject]).enabled=YES;
    NSLog(@"O_O: %li",(long)((UIButton *)[btns firstObject]).tag);
    [btns removeObject:[btns firstObject]];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the timer in the model not the view.

Comment: I tried putting the timer in the singleton model. Still same problem

Comment: You don't need a singleton for this. Each cell is represented by some data (probably stored in an array). Put the timer in that data. Not in the view.

Comment: Post image and your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: I used singleton to keep the track of the timer even if the user left the view .. So if the user comes back i still can keep track of the timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think about it like this - *my model does the work, the cell only shows what is going on*.

Therefore, you add the timer outside of the scope of `UITableViewCell`, and in `cellForRow` you'll *"only"* refer to your model and adjust the cell accordingly (enabled/disabled). If you want it to tick down (~ show live countdown), you need to fire `NSNotification` and catch it with the cells view to have it ticking down. Or then there are always frameworks such as [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) or [SwiftBond](https://github.com/SwiftBond/Bond) where you bond views to certain logic and they react upon it.

If you don't separate it, you'll end up with exactly what you're describing - the reusable cell will reset itself.

Comment: The timer is in a singleton .. So it is outside the cell.. Still same problem.

Comment: That doesn't matter if it's in a singleton, decorator, visitor or facade. That has nothing to do with the approach for this. Could you post some code so I can fully understand your structure?

Comment: `[[Manager btns]containsObject:cell.btn]` this is a problem. Don't refer to the button because there are only few buttons that get reused, so that's why the same button would reappear in other cells. Refer to a **UNIQUE** value - such as `indexPath`.

Comment: how to access the indexPath from the buttonClick function ?

Comment: If you have a flat one dimensional model (= only one section), then I'd simply save the number of the row in `cellForIndex...` into the button's `tag`. If you have multiple sections, then simply override UIButton and give it a field `indexPath` where you'd store it.

Comment: `if([[Manager btns_indexPaths]containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])` i used that still same issue.

Comment: The problem solved as suggested. By using the notification and indexpaths.